# What constitutes a 'field' for the cut command?

Tags: linux, cut

For example, the `cut` command can take a parameter -f, which according to `man`

> select  only  these fields;  also print any line that contains no
>                 delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified

In this context, what is a field?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The term "field" is often times associated with tools such as `cut` and `awk`. A field would be similar to a columns worth of data, if you take the data and separate it using a specific character. Typically the character used to do this is a <kbd>Space</kbd>.

However as is the case with most tools, it's configurable. For example:

- awk = `awk -F"," ...` - would separate by commas (i.e. <kbd>,</kbd>).
- cut = `cut -d"," ...` - would separate by commas (i.e. <kbd>,</kbd>).

#### Examples

This first one shows how `awk` automatically will split on spaces.

```
$ echo "The rain in Spain." | awk '{print $1" "$4}'
The Spain.
```

This one shows how `cut` will split on spaces too.

```
$ echo "The rain in Spain." | cut -d" " -f1,4
The Spain.
```

Here we have a CSV list of column data that we're using `cut` to return columns 1 & 4.

```
$ echo "col1,col2,col3,co4" | cut -d"," -f1,4
col1,co4
```

Awk too can do this:

```
$ echo "col1,col2,col3,co4" | awk -F"," '{print $1","$4}'
col1,co4
```

Awk is also a little more adept at dealing with a variety of separation characters. Here it's dealing with <kbd>Tabs</kbd> along with <kbd>Spaces</kbd> where they're inter-mixed at the same time:

```
$ echo -e "The\t rain\t\t in Spain." | awk '{print $1" "$4}'
The Spain.
```

#### What about the -s switch to cut?

With respect to this switch, it's simply telling `cut` to not print any lines which do not contain the delimiter character specified via the `-d` switch.

#### Example

Say we had this file.

```
$ cat sample.txt 
This is a space string.
This is a space   and   tab string.
Thisstringcontainsneither.
```

**NOTE:** There are spaces and tabs in the 2nd string above.

Now when we process these strings using `cut` with and without the `-s` switch:

```
$ cut -d" " -f1-6 sample.txt 
This is a space string.
This is a space  
Thisstringcontainsneither.

$ cut -d" " -f1-6 -s sample.txt 
This is a space string.
This is a space
```

In the 2nd example you can see that the `-s` switch has omitted any strings from the output that do not contain the delimiter, <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

A field according to POSIX is any part of a line delimited by any of the characters in [`IFS`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03), the "[*input field separator* (or *internal field separator*).](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)" The default value of this is space, followed by a horizontal tabulator, followed by a newline. With Bash you can run `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` to see its value.

Comment: Do a `echo '$IFS' | cat -vet ` to see how default value looks like in the `shell`.

Comment: IFS is used by the shell for most purposes (not all), but not by other programs and specifically not by `cut` which was the question asked.

Comment: Unlike awk, cut also supports only one delimiter at a time, so `cut -d "$IFS"` will error, whereas `awk -F"[ \t\n]"` works as expected

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the utility in question, but for `cut`, a "field" starts at the beginning of a line of text, and includes everything up to the first tab. The second field runs from the character after the first tab, up to the next tab. And so on for third, fourth, ...  Everything between tabs, or between start-of-line and tab, or between tab and end-of-line.

Unless you specify a field delimiter with the "-d" option: `cut -d: -f2` would get you everything between first and second colon (':') characters.

Other utilities have different definitions, but a tab-character is common. `awk` is a good fall back if `cut` is too strict, as `awk` divides fields based on one or more whitespace characters. That's a little bit more natural in a lot of situations, but you have to know a bit of syntax. To print the second field according to `awk`:

```
awk '{print $2}'
```

`sort` is the one that tricks me. My current `sort` man page says something like
"non-blank to blank transition" for a field seperator. For some reason it takes a few tries to get `sort` fields defined correctly. `join` apparently uses "delimited by whitespace" fields, which is what `awk` purports to do by default.

The moral of the story is to be careful, and experiment if you don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The term "field" is not related to linux in general, but to specific programs. So `cut` uses a different kind of field than `sort`.

With `cut`, you define what is a field yourself, by specifying a field delimiter with the option -d, which separates the fields in each line.

If your data is separated by colons in the lines, you can combine `-d` and `-f` to get fields (or columns) 2, 3 and 6 like this:

```
echo 'a:b:c::d:e:f' | cut -d : -f 2-3,6
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `cut` command then it takes two main arguments

> -d : which stand for delimiter
>
> -f : which stand for field to be cut from the input file

```
Ex. cut - d "|"  - f1, 2 input_filename
```

Here the `output` would be separated by delimiter "|"  and it will cut only 2 fields from the input file

If you have following lines in your file

```
Alex|120000|Admin|1999
```

Then it will cut 2 fields which are

```
Alex|120000
```

Comment: Your example is completely broken due to incorrect spaces, and even if correct this adds nothing to answers given 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` is great for simple cases, where the delimiter is a single character and you want to output a subset of the input fields, in the same order (even if I specify `-f3,2,1`, it acts the same as `-f1,2,3`).

`awk` one-liners are much more flexible, e.g. when the input field separator might be any whitespace (`awk`'s default), or when you want to output fields in a different order or with a particular format.

For example `wc -l myfile | awk '{print $1}'` or `ls -l file1 file2 | awk '{printf "%s,%s:%s\n", $9, $7, $3}'` are very simple, but would be hard to do with `cut`.

I agree with earlier posters that fields/keys in `sort` are tough to figure out!
Fields in `join` seem to work the same as in `cut`, although `join` options are easy to get wrong.